# Scrolling Tab Bar with Navigation Tab in each view

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Project need to show 7 tab bars in the application. So as per TabBar controller I am able to show the 4 tabs at a time along with "More" button which after clicking shows remaining tabs.

Also I need to show Navigation Tab for each View.

I am able to achieve this till now. But we need to make the Tab Bar in scrolling manner so that user can scroll the remaining tabs and after clicking particular tab that view is loaded along with Navigation Controller.

So can any body tell me how to achieve Scrolling TabBar along with Navigation bar in each view.
Any sample code will be more great full......

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the "more"-button... This should be the way to manage too many tabs, in order not to break the common iPhone l&f and keep users on track.